# Load and append external html file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to load external HTML file with a content like this:

```
{"html":" \n <font>\u043b\u0432.<\/font> \n ","back":""}
```

I tried with this code - it loads the file but it remains with \n and the other things..

```
<div id="success"></div>
<script>$.get('test.html', function(data) { $(data).appendTo("#success"); } );</script>
```

Comment: Font tags are deprecated. Do not use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified code: Since your data is a JSON object you should use `$.getJSON` . and replace all `\n` with `<br>`.

```
<script>
   $.getJSON('test.html', function(data) {
      data =data.html.replace(/\n/g, "<br>"); 
      $(data).appendTo("#success"); } );
</script>
```

Comment: I tried to use it with http:// but here's what I get when I see the Chrome's Console (and it returns blank page): XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://daytona.bg/test.html. Origin http://127.0.0.1 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: That means you trying to access cross domain apis. which not allowed by browser. you have to use JSONP.

Comment: You mean to change getJSON to getJSONP? I tried it and it give me this error now: Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new p.fn.init(a,b,c)} has no method 'getJSONP'

Comment: Yes, there is no such method. use of JSONP is different see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP. can you post browser url and url you trying to access. I just want see if both are pointing to same domain or different.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using appendTo, do the following:

```
<div id="success"></div>
<script>$.get('test.html', function(data) { $("#success").html(data); } );</script>
```

Please beware: If you don't control the contents of "data", you're exposing yourself to XSS attacks. If you do, it is ok.